# Visualforce page saying Constructor is not visible

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, user-record

I am designing an empty VF page which has a controller which has a constructor which is being used to update values on user record but whenever I try to save the page it says Constructor is not visible.

This is my controller

```
public with sharing class reactivateUser {
    reactivateUser(){
        String userId= UserInfo.getUserId();
        User currentUser = [select lmscons__CFS_Status__c from user where id =: userid];
        currentUser.lmscons__CFS_Status__c = 'Active';
        update currentUser;    
   }
}
```

This is my VF page

```
 <apex:page controller="reactivateUser">
 <div> Your account was deactivated due to inactivity.You will be redirected to next page after reactivation now.
 </div>
 </apex:page>
```

Exact error message

> Constructor is not visible: [reactivateUser]<init>(): Markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points. First you need to make it public. Second you can't make DML in constructor so create a method and put your DML there and call that method from your page's action attribute.

Class

```
public with sharing class reactivateUser {
    public reactivateUser(){

   }
   public void reactivateUserMethod(){
        String userId= UserInfo.getUserId();
        User currentUser = [select lmscons__CFS_Status__c from user where id =: userid];
        currentUser.lmscons__CFS_Status__c = 'Active';
        update currentUser;    
   }
}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="reactivateUser" action="{!reactivateUserMethod}">
 <div> Your account was deactivated due to inactivity.You will be redirected to next page after reactivation now.
 </div>
 </apex:page>
```